# Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent $N(0, \sigma^2)$ random variables. What is the distribution of $X_1^2 + X_2^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent $N(0, \sigma^2)$ which means (mean = 0, variance = $\sigma^2$) random variables. What is the distribution of $X_1^2 + X_2^2$?

My approach is that 
$X_1\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $X_2\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

Then $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$ have chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom. (I am not sure the degree of freedom and not sure how to show it as well(please help on this))

Then I found the moment-generating function for $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$;$$m_{X_1^2} = (1-2t)^{-1/2}$$ and $$m_{X_2^2} = (1-2t)^{-1/2}$$

So the moment generating function for $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ is $$m_{X_1^2}(t) m_{X_2^2}(t) = (1-2t)^{-2/2}$$

So $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ has a chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. Is this correct?

Comment: Try computing $P\{X_1^2+X_2^2\leq z\}$, where $z>0$, via a change from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. It is _easy_ to solve the resulting double integral. So you know the CDF of $X_1^2+X_2^2$ for positive values of $z$, and should be able to differentiate it to get the density function for $z> 0$. For $z\leq 0$, you are on your own to figure out the answer.

Comment: the answer is asking what is the distribution of $X_1^2 + X_2^2$...don't I just need to give an answer like chi-squared with six degree of freedom (made up answer).

Comment: **After** getting the density function, you might be able to make a statement like that _if the result looks like something you have seen before._  I can assure you that if you had simply stated as your answer something like your  "chi-square with six degrees of freedom" with no work to support it in any of my classes over a 35-year career teaching this stuff, you would have received a grade of 0 even if your description of the distribution were absolutely correct.  Do some work yourself instead of posting your entire homework here and getting someone to write up answers for you.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I just post my approach. Could you take a look if they are right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: My approach focuses on $\sigma^2 = 1$. I guess if I do not restrict to 1, the degree of freedom is the only thing that I need to change right?

Comment: I still do not see how I can modify my answer for $\sigma^2 \neq 1$...Could you give some help on this?

Comment: Take a look at my added solution on the duplicate post...I want to see if you like it better than this, purely uses distribution identification and transformations @DilipSarwate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables, then
for any $z \geq 0$,
$$\begin{align}
P\{X^2+Y^2 > z\} &= \int_{x^2+y^2>z}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\\
&= \int_{x^2+y^2>z}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\\
&= \int_{\sqrt{z}}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot r\,\mathrm d\theta\cdot \mathrm dr\\
&= \int_{\sqrt{z}}^\infty \frac{r}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\, \mathrm dr\\
&= \left. -\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right|_{\sqrt{z}}^\infty\\
&= \exp(-z/2\sigma^2).
\end{align}$$
Now, if $Z$ is an *exponential* random variable with parameter $\lambda$, then
$P\{Z > z\} = \exp(-\lambda z)$, and so $X^2+Y^2$ is a $\ldots$

Comment: How do you get from second equality to third equality?

Comment: just to confirm $X^2 + Y^2$ follows a exponential distribution with$ 1/2\sigma^2$, right?

Comment: What's wrong???

Comment: Just realized: the parameter should be $1/\lambda$...it should $2\sigma^2$?

Comment: Take a look at my added solution on the duplicate post...I want to see if you like it better than this, purely uses distribution identification and transformations @DilipSarwate

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look up "Chi-squared distribution"

Comment: I just post my approach. Could you take a look if they are right?

Answer (score 0):

I  found an easier way to solve this using Chi-square properties and transformations.

Step 1: $ \frac{X_{1}^2}{\sigma^2} \ is\ \chi^2 (1)$;

Step 2:$ \frac{X_{1}^2}{\sigma^2}+ \frac{X_{2}^2}{\sigma^2}\  is\  \chi^2 (2)$;

Step 3: $\sigma^2(\frac{X_{1}^2}{\sigma^2}+ \frac{X_{2}^2}{\sigma^2})=(X_{1}^2+X_{2}^2)$;

Step 4: Find the distribution of $\sigma^2*\chi^2(2)$ through a transformation;

Basically, it is a non-central $\chi^2(2)$.

It is a relatively easier process than the first approach.